# JQuery Can't alert doesn't work

Tags: jquery

What im trying to do is just to output and alert box whenever the user input something in the input field. I have two files which is `index.php` & `popup_script.js`.
here are my codes so far.

### file: index.php

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/popup_script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
</body>
```

### file: popup_script.js

```
$('#input').keyup( function (){
    alert('you entered something on the input box');
});
```

I'm new to JQuery.

Comment: Im working on windows and using Sublime text 3 as a word editing software.

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"></script>` before your script

Comment: also you have to use document.ready

Answer (score 1):

You need to include jQuery in your file first.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/popup_script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
</body>
```

And wrap all your DOM queries inside $(document).ready():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#input').keyup( function (){ alert('you entered something on the input box'); });
})
```

Comment: how would i do that ?

Comment: same it doesn't output an alert box :(

Comment: Updated the answer. Spend some time to know the library. http://learn.jquery.com/ is a good place to start.

Comment: Do you have the file `popup_script.js` inside the `scripts` folder?

Comment: yes and thanks its the <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> that i didnt include :) thank u so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you include Jquery before ?

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

See your code with jquery include : http://jsbin.com/IDOsIPiG/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery via it's own `<script>` tag, it's not built into the browser. Then, you need to put your DOM-accessing code either below the markup, or in a [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) callback.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#input').keyup( function (){ alert('you entered something on the input box'); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the code inside $(document).ready(function() {
... yourcode ...}

the element is does not exist when you try to select it